# Issue with Populating Verified Latitude and Longitude Fields in Salesforce Maps Geocoding Batch

Tags: automation, sales-cloud

I am currently facing an issue related to geocoding records using Salesforce Maps. Although the batch process successfully fills the standard Latitude and Longitude fields, I am experiencing difficulties populating the Verified Latitude and Verified Longitude fields.

I have followed the documentation and created the necessary fields for Verified Latitude and Verified Longitude. Additionally, I have correctly configured the Base object as instructed. However, despite these steps, the Verified Latitude and Verified Longitude fields remain empty after running the geocoding batch process.

I have attached screenshots showcasing the setup of the fields and the mapping configuration for your reference.

I would like your assistance in identifying any potential misconfigurations or additional steps required to ensure the population of the Verified Latitude and Verified Longitude fields during the geocoding process. Any insights, recommendations, or troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your support and expertise.

**Map Setup**
[image]

**Queried Records**
[image]